# I'm trying to get user friends list from facebook using curl. but it returns empty data

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

My code is:-

```
$user = $socialUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
$frd = $this->getFriendsFB($user->token, $user->id);
```

`getFriendsFb()` Function defination is:-

```
public function getFriendsFB($token, $id = null)
    {
        $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/$id/friends?access_token=$token";
        $type = "GET";
        $out = $this->getCurlRequestForFacebook($url, $type);
        return $out;
    }
```

`getCurlRequestForFacebook` function definition is:-

```
public function getCurlRequestForFacebook($url, $type)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $type);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $out = json_decode($output);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $out;
}
```

In the output, I'm getting empty data and i've 2 friends in fb A/C. Find a screenshot of output :- https://prnt.sc/jl19w2 
You can found that there are 2 friends but data is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook only returns the list of those friends that have previously used your application. If none have used your app till now, you will get an empty array.

Comment: Yes, Its working after connecting  app with friends facebook.

Thanks